# Delphi call functions from different class levels

Tags: delphi

How to call functions from individual parent classes, function should have the identical name as in the parent class.

In Java there is the `super` keyword, in C# there is `base`. What is the equivalent in Delphi?

```
type 
  MyParentClass = class
    function Dosomething: Integer;
  end;

  MyChildClass = class(MyParentClass)
    function DoSomething: Integer;
  end;

  MyGrandChildClass = class(MyChildClass)
    function DoSomething: Integer;
  end;


function MyParentClass.Dosomething : Integer;
begin
      result := 5; 
end;


function MyChildClass.Dosomething : Integer;
begin
      result := Dosomething + 15 ;  // result should be 20 !  
end;


function MyGrandChildClass.Dosomething : Integer;
begin
      result := Dosomething + 40 ;  // result should be 60  .....   
end;
```

Comment: should be fixed now

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505695/how-to-access-base-super-class-in-delphi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `inherited` keyword:

```
function MyChildClass.DoSomething : Integer;
begin
  result := inherited DoSomething + 15 ;
end;
```

Read about this keyword at the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Inherited).

If you wish to pick out a class further up the inheritance chain then you have to name it explicitly. For example:

```
function MyGrandChildClass.DoSomething : Integer;
begin
  result := MyParentClass(Self).DoSomething + 15 ;
end;
```

Note however, that all of this is a very strong code smell. In each derived class you are hiding the method of the same name. Usually this should be done with a virtual method.

Comment: Main question: how to call function from MyParentClass ? `inherited Dosomething ` call only from last parent.

Comment: @Zam Not by my reading. After all, the question explicitly refers to `base` from C#.